# Why won't my exported PDF fully load all the text on each page when opening?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export

GD beginner here. I created a multi-paged document with InDesign. It's not too complicated, just some background images and text with headers. When sending as a PDF, the pages are loading one by one and slowly. Each line of text loads separately and the whole page will take 15 seconds or so to completely load. It's exported as the smallest file size. What else can I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, how big is the file size? Does it take a long time to load the PDF on other peoples computers? Maybe check your task manager/activity monitor to see if you're maxed on RAM. Does it take long time to load other PDF's? Does your design have a lot of Vector points?

Comment: Andrew, It's 11.3 MB. It does have a few vector images if that's what you mean. This problem was brought up to me when I sent it over to a coworker. Works fine on mine as do other PDFs.

Comment: That isn't very big for a PDF. If the PDF loads fine on your machine and poorly on another machine then my guess is that the issue is with the other computer. This question is better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) but I don't think you have enough information for any of us to really give a definitive answer. I would try opening the PDF either on your phone or another computer to see if it really is the PDF.

Comment: Does this include any outlined text or very complicated vector graphics?

Comment: That sounds like an issue with your coworkers computer. Pehaps his computer might not be up to the job, or perhaps he just has too many documents open, too many programs running, a slow internet connection (if downloading), etc, etc - the possibilities for such problems are endless.  11MB for a PDF is not a large file.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an issue with the PDF and not the computer. You can start by auditing space usage. That will tell you what is taking up the most of the space in your file.

Choose File > Save As Other > Optimized PDF. The PDF Optimizer dialog box opens.

Click the Audit Space Usage button at the top of the dialog box.

Adobe DC documentation 
https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/optimizing-pdfs-acrobat-pro.html

If you have very complex vectors in you PDF you will see a large amount of space dedicated to content streams. Which can increase the time and resources needed to renderer.